# Is it possible to implement oauth2 autentication in google ads without browser?

Tags: java, browser, oauth-2.0, ads

Is it possible to implement oauth2 autentication in google ads without browser (in JAVA)?
I download http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-java/ and examples.
There are example of oauth2 autentication with help of browser
Is it possible to do it without browser?
If possible then how?
There are button in browser with:
*Allow acces / no thanks*
How to solve it?

Comment: Participating in OAuth without a browser in the loop to handle the mess of redirects, javascript and cookie handling that is usually present? Tricky. Very tricky. What were you seeking to do with it? (I didn't think I had to log into a site in an app to see ads in it, but what do I know…)

Answer (score 0):

You have few options for OAuth2 [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) and I think [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount) doesn't require user consent - but I didn't found any examples how to use it.

In my implementation I've done something a little bit ugly and I've used Selenium which goes to webpage and grants access.
It looks something like that:

```java
    final WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.get(url);
    try {
        final WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("submit_approve_access"));
        element.click();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
        //we aren't logged so first we log in then next we click approve
        final WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
        final WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));

        login.sendKeys(email);
        password.sendKeys(passwd);

        password.submit();
        // logged in

        final WebElement aproveButton = driver.findElement(By.id("submit_approve_access"));
        aproveButton.submit();
        // oauth approved
    } finally {
        driver.close();
    }
```